# How do you move the mouse to all of the blue pixels on the screen's x y values averaged

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am trying to make a DIY Virtual Reality kit, and am not sufficient in Python. But by far, I think Python is the only way to achieve the following; The program takes each frame from the webcam feed, get's the blue pixels, and averages all of the XY positions of the pixels, and makes the mouse move there. In OpenCV and Python.

I've done a milion Google searches and cannot find what I need. I spent around 11 hours searching the OpenCV documentation and found nothing. I just need this program done. I'm running Python 3.7.3, and with OpenCV 2.

Any help would be much appreciated. I am fine with people giving me the full code as long as it is understandable and is legible.

Thank you.

*Edit, I am using Windows x86.

Comment: Man, this is a place for asking questions, solving doubts of problems you are dealing with. Not to ask for someone to work in your place.
I understand you are a beginner. That's why you need to try solving it yourself. Or you're never going to learn. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image to HSV. HSV is better for detection specific coloured areas generally. [This SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817133/identifying-the-range-of-a-color-in-hsv-using-opencv) deals with the same issue as you described and have useful links on them. After you detect blue pixels with inRange function, use the mask to get an average of coordinate values(np.argwhere is useful for getting coordinates, then use np.mean over axis=0).

Comment: Can you provide some code, please? I just started learning Python. I don't know what this means.